# The series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{k^{\lfloor{\log_m(n)}\rfloor}}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, logarithms, closed-form

This may be quite simple, but I am having trouble proving the closed form of this sum.

$$S(m,k)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{k^{\lfloor{\log_m(n)}\rfloor}}$$

which converges for $m \lt k$.

From experimenting, it appears that the solution is $S(m,k)=\frac{km-k}{k-m}$ but how would we prove it.

Comment: I would be *extremely* impressed if it had a closed form, let alone one as simple as that.

Comment: @Fimpellizieri It's not that complicated really.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The point is that because of the floor function in the exponent, the sum consists of groups of equal terms which can easily be added.  Specifically,

- for $n$ from $1$ to $m-1$ there are $m-1$ terms, each equal to $\frac1{k^0}=1$;
- for $n$ from $m$ to $m^2-1$ there are $m^2-m$ terms, each equal to $\frac1{k^1}$;
- for $n$ from $m^2$ to $m^3-1$ there are $m^3-m^2$ terms, each equal to $\frac1{k^2}$;
- and so on.  The total turns out to be a geometric series:
  $$S(m,k)=(m-1)+\frac{m^2-m}{k}+\frac{m^3-m^2}{k^2}+\cdots
    =\frac{m-1}{1-\frac mk}
    =\frac{km-k}{k-m}\ .$$

Comment: Huh, that's pretty nice. Just a geometric series 'in disguise'.

Answer (score 0):

$$S(m,k)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{k^{\lfloor{\log_m(n)}\rfloor}}$$

Note that $\lfloor\log_m(n)\rfloor$ for  increasing $n$ has the same value first $m^1-m^0$ times, then $m^2-m^1$ times, then $m^3-m^2$ times, etc... And those values it takes on are $0, 1, 2, \dots$.

So we can rewrite the sum:

$$S(m,k)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{m^{n+1} - m^{n}}{k^n} = \frac{km - k }{k-m}$$